# mysql upgrade script not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql-config

Below is the my config.xml file

```
<resources>
                <categoryrestrict_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Exinent_Categoryrestrict</module>
                        <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </categoryrestrict_setup>
                <categoryrestrict_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </categoryrestrict_write>
                <categoryrestrict_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </categoryrestrict_read>
            </resources>
```

and my upgrade file name is upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php but it is not working

Comment: show the full config.xml file code

Comment: <modules>
        <Exinent_Categoryrestrict>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Exinent_Categoryrestrict>
    </modules>

Comment: i think your mysql install file name from the sql/categoryrestrict_setup is mysql4-install-1.0.0.php . m i right

Comment: please check core_resource table under categoryrestrict_setup what is the version number their ?

Answer (score 2):

or just check your config.xml line should be something like this

```
<modules>
    <YourPackageName_YourModuleName>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </YourPackageName_YourModuleName>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure that you have increased the version in your config.xml, you need something like this:

```
<modules>
    <YOURNAMESPACE_YOUREXTENSIONNAME>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </YOURNAMESPACE_YOUREXTENSIONNAME>
</modules>
<global>
    <resources>
```

After debugging the script be sure that your setup version is one before in the database. To run it again, you can find and change the version in the table core_resource.

Comment: Just add one more point that you need to give full permission to your   /var/www/your-project/app/code/local/YOURPACKAGE/sql  folder also.